# How to retry fetching xml when malformed/unexpected reply is returned?

Tags: php, curl, xml-parsing

Can you give me some idea how to improve this function so it handles unexpected reply when server returns output that is not in xml, eg a simple server error message in html and then retry fetching the xml?

```php
function fetch_xml($url, $timeout=15)
{
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        CURLOPT_HEADER => 0,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => (int)$timeout,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
        CURLOPT_URL => $url)
    );

    $xml_data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    if (!empty($xml_data)) {
        return new SimpleXmlElement($xml_data);

    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: `SimpleXmlElement` will `Produces an E_WARNING error message for each error found in the XML data and additionally throws an Exception if the XML data could not be parsed.` Just check for an Exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give this a try. I haven't tested it out.

```
function fetch_xml($url, $timeout = 15, $max_attempts = 5, $attempts = 0)
{
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        CURLOPT_HEADER => 0,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => (int)$timeout,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
        CURLOPT_URL => $url)
    );

    $xml_data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    if ($attempts <= $max_attempts && !empty($xml_data)) // don't infinite loop
    {
        try
        {
            return new SimpleXmlElement($xml_data);
        } 
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            return fetch_xml($url, (int)$timeout, $max_attempts, $attempts++);
        } 
    }
    return NULL;
}
```